# leaflet routing machine HTTP request failed

Tags: leaflet, leaflet-routing-machine

I want to calculation the duration between to geolocalisation using leaflet routing machine but i got this error.

```
> message: "HTTP request failed: error" status: -1 target: ProgressEvent
> {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, total: 0, type:
> "error", …} url:
> "https://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/car/2.279049917924877,48.83924675;2.2893811,48.8538898?overview=false&alternatives=true&steps=true&hints=;"
> __proto__: Object
```

Any solutions ?

Comment: have you tried it with http?

Comment: yes its work with http, but how could I change its ?

Answer (score 0):

you should overwrite the service url since https is not valid

use this property in options

`serviceUrl: 'http://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1'`